# Finding all Sub ranges for a list of ranges (one or more)

Tags: algorithm

I have some files which are written between Start Time and End Time as follows;

```
[0 , 1] , [1,2] , [2 , 3] , [3, 4] , [4, 7] , [7, 8]
```

I want to find all the sub ranges for the time between 2 and 5 with O(N);
For above example:

```
[1,2] , [2 , 3] , [3, 4] , [4, 7]
```

This works if I write condition like below

```
if (StartTime >= 2 and StartTime <= 5) or (EndTime >=2 and EndTime <= 5)
    add this to your list of sub ranges
```

But this fails if I have a single range:

```
[0,8]
```

and I am searching for file between 2 and 5

Can anyone suggest how to do this?

Comment: `if (StartTime >= 2 and StartTime <= 5) or (EndTime >=2 and EndTime <= 5) or (StartTime <= 2 and EndTime >= 5) add to list of sub ranges`?

Comment: @COLDSPEED , yes this work but this logic looks little clumsy , I was wondering if there is a simpler comparison

Answer (score 1):

Note that intervals A and B overlap if

```
 (A.Start <= B.End) and (B.Start <= A.End)
```

Example:

```
 A = [2,5]
 B = [0,8]
 (A.Start <= B.End) and (B.Start <= A.End)
  (2<=8) and (0<=5)  is True, so they overlap
```

P.S. In general case it's worth to use dedicated data structures like interval tree to achieve better asymptotic time.

Comment: Sorry I didnt get your meaning , can you please specify answer with respect to starttime and endtime and 2 , 5

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
if(startTime<=5 && endTime>=2);
```

OR

```
if(max(startTime,2)<=min(endTime,5));
```

This will work in all conditions.